# Manifest Merger Failed: uses-sdk:minSDKVersion1 cannot be smaller than 7

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

[image: Log]

After I imported the BaseGameUtils module (for Google Play Game Services), I got this error. The error log says to use in my Module Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"/>
```

Then, when I build this happens:

[image]

Then, the errorLog suggests me to import this into my Module's Manifest File:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4"/>
```

Then, I get the first error again, It's a never-ending back and forth cycle.

App Manifest XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="reflexflash.gespanet2015.com.flashreflex">


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Arcade1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

App Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "reflexflash.gespanet2015.com.flashreflex"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {

compile project(':BaseGameUtils')

}
```

Module Manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.google.example.games.basegameutils"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4"/>

<application>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Module Gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
  }
}

dependencies {

// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of  BasicSamples
if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
    ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
    ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
    ext.gms_library_version = '8.1.0'
}

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-      games:${gms_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services- plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of  BasicSamples
if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
    ext.android_compile_version = 23
}
if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
    ext.android_version = '23'
}

compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
buildToolsVersion android_version
```

Comment: What is your gradle file? Change the `minSdk` in your gradle file.

Comment: *Edited* both grade's are now included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Module's manifest, i added this line to fix it:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

my minSdkVersion is also stated in my app's gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your gradle (app).

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 7 //here your problem. Change that 1 to 7(or value of the that you are currently using libraries)
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you share us your gradle via updating your question